# Entity Framework 6 and .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have been reading about .NET Core and *[ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2)*.

It states

> The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core application
> is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class library project that
> targets the full framework. Add a reference to the class library from the
> ASP.NET Core project.

However, when I actually do the following.

1. Create a console application based on .NET Core
2. Create Class library based on the .NET full framework.
3. In the class library, add EDMX and link it with a SQL database.
4. Refer to the class library in the .NET Core application.

It will not let me compile with the following error:

> The Type DbSet is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

This means I have to add an [ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework) reference to the console application, but it will not allow me to as a .NET Core application does not support the full Entity Framework.

Surely, I am missing something or getting the post mentioned above wrong.

What is the issue?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not use EFCore?

Comment: yes, because i am trying this for a scenario where entity framework implementation can't be changed, but the project has to go to .net core

Comment: EF 6.3 will be supported in .NET Core 3 (currently in Preview 1): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/

Comment: @MandarJogalekar that's a rather unrealistic scenario. Moving to .NET Core means a lot has to change already. EF Core is the fully supported version going forward, EF 6.3 and later are essentially in maintenance mode

Comment: @MandarJogalekar it sounds like the *real* question is how to use EDMX, not EF 6.  Database-First [is available in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) and doesn't need an EDMX file. Even in EF6, you can reverse-engineer a database into code-first classes. EDMX is the EF 4-5 way of working. It's something you'll have to migrate away from anyway

Comment: Ef 6.3 works for .net Core. To get the EDMX file to work. Look here for the current workaround:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/#ef-designer-support

Answer (score 3):

From Entity Framework 6.3 onward you'll be able to use EF6.x with .NET Core rather than having to switch to EF Core.

From Diego Vega's blog post [Announcing Entity Framework 6.3 Preview with .NET Core Support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/):

> **What is new in EF 6.3?**
>
> While Entity Framework Core was built from the ground up to work on .NET Core, 
>   6.3 will be the first version of
>   EF 6 that can run on .NET Core and work cross-platform. In fact, the
>   main goal of this release is to facilitate migrating existing
>   applications that use EF 6 to .NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2) you provide is clear:

> To use Entity Framework 6, your project has to compile against .NET
>   Framework, as Entity Framework 6 doesn't support .NET Core. If you
>   need cross-platform features you will need to upgrade to Entity
>   Framework Core.

Create a new ASP.NET Core and target to full .NET instead of Core.